# How to implement add to cart functionality in spring boot and calculate subtotals?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have products page with a button to add to cart. I'm looking for an elegant way to present this scenario. Currently adding to cart is submitting to an entity cart items.I want to an elegant solution that involves finding subtotals. Here is my code effort for adding to cart soo far.

**Product Model**

```
    public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long carId;
    private String carImage;
    private String carModel;
     private Long milleage;
     private double price;

    //getters and seters
   }
```

**CartItems Model**

```
public class CartItems {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
private Product product;

private double subTotal;

String username;

//setters getter

}
```

**CartItemsService to add to cart**

```
public void addToCart(Long carId, CartItems cartItems, String username){

Product product = productRepository.findById(carId).orElse(null);
    cartItems.setProduct(product);

        cartItems.setSubTotal(product.getPrice());
        cartItems.setUsername(username);

        cartItemsRepository.save(cartItems);

}
public List<CartItems> myCart(String userName){

    List<CartItems> cartItems = new ArrayList<>();
    cartItemsRepository.findByUsername(userName).forEach(cartItems::add);

    return cartItems;
}
```

**Controller**

```
 @PostMapping("/addToCart/{carId}")
public String addToCart(@PathVariable Long carId, @ModelAttribute CartItems cartItems, Principal principal){

    //to save to cartItem table.
    cartService.addToCart(carId, cartItems, principal.getName());

    return "products";
}

@GetMapping("/myCart")
public  String myCart ( @AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal, Model model){

   List<CartItems> cartItems =  cartService.myCart(principal.getName());
   model.addAttribute("cartItems",cartItems);
    return "myCart";
}
```

This approach is saving the cart items to the table. Incase a user does not check out.

````
+----+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| id | sub_total | product_car_id | username  |
+----+-----------+----------------+-----------+
|  4 |   7500000 |              2 | Developer |
|  5 |   4500000 |              4 | Developer |
+----+-----------+----------------+-----------+```


I'm terribly stuck at finding the subtotals and as well i feel this is not an elegant solution to implement add to cart functionality in spring boot and spring data jpa + thymeleaf.
Please help me with insights and code samples... thank you
````

Comment: You just showing the code and don't explain what is the problem with it. What is wrong?

Comment: "This approach is saving the cart items to the table." i said i'm looking for an elegant solution.  and how to calcuate subtotals.

Comment: Define "elegant". Until there's a strict criteria, what I consider elegant and you might consider elegant are just our own opinions, which are off-topic for this site.

Comment: Sorry, may be i asked a wrong question if you approve my approach shown above.

Comment: This is a code review question then. Assumng it works as you expect, you can get feedback on https://codereview.stackexchange.com If it doesn't work, however, then you should explain exactly what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll repost on code review